# Checking for equality in lists in SML

Tags: equality, sml

i want to write a function that checks for equality of lists in SML
for instance :

```
[1,2,3]=[1,2,3];
val it = true : bool
```

So instead of writing down the whole thing, i want to make a function that takes two predefined lists, and compare them, so that if `list01` is `[1,2,3]` and `list09` is `[1,2,3]`
then `fun equal (list01, list09);` will return `-val it = true : bool;`

Comment: What do you mean by "writing down the whole thing"? Writing `equal (list01, list09)` is actually longer than writing `list01 = list09`, so what's the "whole thing" you want to avoid writing?

Comment: i assumed it would be easier to create a function compare ([list01,list09]); than actually compare the two lists manually, if they were very! long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a not checked sample:

```
fun compare ([], []) = true # both empty
  | compare (x::xs, y::ys) = (x = y) and compare(xs,ys)
  | compare (_, _) = false # different lengths
```

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be aware that `=` works on lists, so (as I already said in my comment) I don't see why you need to define an `equal` function.

That being said, you can just write:

```
fun equal (a, b) = (a = b);
```